# JMX Connection Refused, only when linking Jaas Kerberos module

Tags: java, unix, jmx, kerberos, jaas

I am getting the following error when trying to access an exposed mbean process using JMX.

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.65.13.201; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.checkSslConfig(ProxyClient.java:217)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.<init>(ProxyClient.java:110)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.getProxyClient(ProxyClient.java:463)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.JConsole$3.run(JConsole.java:510)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:22)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:128)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:595)
    ... 8 more
```

I am on a Unix server, and I am running using the following command:

```
java -jar MBeanSecure.jar 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=jmxremote.access 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1234 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas-krb5.conf 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.login.config=client 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.65.13.201
com.ba.running.RunningImplem
```

My Hostname -i gives me:

```
$ hostname -i
10.65.13.201
```

All my config files are set to rw 0600, so this is:

```
jaas-krb5.conf
jmxremote.access
```

It appears to be specific to the Jaas config set up, because I am able to run the jar and access it fine when I use the following command:

```
java -jar 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1234 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=jmxremote.password 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=jmxremote.access 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true MBeanSecure.jar
```

Then I am able to connect via jconsole without issue. So it doesn't appear to be a configuration setting on the server, I believe it's specific to my Jaas login module.

The jaas-krb5.conf:

```
client{
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required;
};
server{
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useKeyTab=false
    storeKey=false
    principal="principal@intranet.com";
};
```

I can confirm also that the Krb5LodingModule is working and communicating with the KDC accurately.

So there appears to be a misconfiguration with JMX when launching the jar, and my question is what that could be?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

incorrect launch script:

```
java -classpath MBeanSecure.jar 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<hostname>
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<port> 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=../path/to/jaaskrb5.conf 
-Djava.security.krb5.conf=../path/to/krb5.conf 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.login.config=client 
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=../path/to/jmxremote.access com.ba.running.RunningImplementation
```